# Is it a good practice to downvote a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvotes

If a question is asked in a proper format, but when you know it has been asked many times, is it a good practice to downvote it!?

Comment: When the poster shows no evidence of effort, and this should include searching for and reviewing similar questions, if they are not difficult to find, then that is a reason to down-vote.

Answer (score 11):

Well, you could argue that it shows no research effort, but if it's otherwise well asked then down-voting could seem a little churlish.

Just vote/flag to close as a duplicate.

One thing to bear in mind is that duplicates can be a good thing. If the question is written in such a way that it's a new way of stating the problem then that's good. It'll turn up on future searches and downvoting will make it more likely that the question is deleted before it can perform this function.