# Should a duplicate be downvoted or just closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm not referring to a bad question. It's just that it's a duplicate. The asker might have searched but not found the previous question. Should we downvote or just link to the previous one (and close as duplicate) and be done with it?

(I'm assuming that this question itself was asked before. But I searched and couldn't find one like it.)

The [suggested dup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357539/is-it-a-good-practice-to-downvote-a-duplicate-question) refers to questions which have been asked many times (and therefore are easy to find). I'm referring to questions which, when searched for on a search engine and on Stack Overflow, return nothing.

So, this question is now closed as a duplicate of a question closed as a duplicate. Something is wrong here...

Comment: close it and downvote where you see no effort make. some questions are still good, even when they are dupes

Comment: That downward facing triangle is basically a *dislike* button. Use it when you don't like a question, whether it's a duplicate or not doesn't matter at all, and no one can question why you chose to do so.

Comment: @gnat Well, the question you linked to _is_ downvoted and closed as a duplicate. But that doesn't prove it for the main site because downvotes on meta mean something else than on the main site.

Comment: Also, that question refers to questions which have been asked many times (and therefore are easy to find). I'm referring to questions which, when searched for on a search engine and on StackOverflow, return nothing.

Comment: There are several known things that piss off a lot of SO/meta voters - adding "searched alot" text to the question is one of them (despite popular belief such phrases do not in any way *demonstrate research effort*), claiming they post if "the bestest evar" (in variety of ways, including "my post is very clear and you just don't get it", "I show all possible code"...); complaining about votes (most common on meta like you shown in your edit). You may want to review your question to make sure there is no such trigger phrases...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov There aren't. They're just here since I'm seeing the meta effect anyway. :) But thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with closing as a duplicate of a duplicate? This is asking the same question as the immediate duplicate, which is in turn a subset of the other one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Downvotes should be made to questions with *no research effort*. If the duplicate is a trivial one that we can get by googling the title then I would downvote the question and close it.

In some cases the duplicate is not a trivial one, and I may upvote the question because it can be a good way to get the duplicate target using different keywords.

Duplicate questions aren't necessarily bad, they can even be good.

Trivial repeated duplicate questions with 0 search effort are bad and should be closed.

Comment: Because it shows no evidence of research, or attempts to fix the problem. Plus it's posted like a bug report, which isn't what [so] is for, @ispiro .

Comment: And yet it's the previous question is upvoted, despite being of poorer quality including being posted "like a bug report". And for the record, I think that everyone understands the implied question is how to fix this. It is obviously _not_ assumed to be a bug.

Comment: `Because it shows no evidence of research` - what research would you expect on something like this? Searching for an answer - I obviously did. And if it weren't obvious, reading the comments would.

Comment: @ispiro maybe they simply found your question *not useful* or *unclear*

Comment: And yet the inferior previous question is upvoted? I don't think so. (Just take a look and you'll see.) But I guess I'll stop arguing here. Asking about downvotes on Meta... What was I thinking?? :)

Comment: @ispiro I said *maybe they ..* I cannot tell you why they downvoted and I don't have any domain knowledge around the subject of the question to judge it myself. I gave my opinion on how duplicate should be handled. I also see trivial duplicates question highly upvoted (https://stackoverflow.com/q/64735248/8620333) like I see good one downvoted

Comment: I don't get how this is accepted by @ispiro as exactly the same "Well, you could argue that it shows no research effort, but if it's otherwise well asked then down-voting could seem a little churlish." from duplicate *does not answer the question* according to them. Very confusing.

Comment: "Downvotes should be made to questions with no research effort" - that's how things go wrong, zooming in on exactly the wrong part especially in meta answers. No, questions which are unclear and/or not useful should be downvoted, no research effort is generally what causes that state but it is not itself the defining reason to downvote something.

Answer (score 9):

I usually classify duplicates into three different categories:

- **Repeated duplicates** that are very easy to find an answer for → should be downvoted, closed, then deleted.
- Questions that require a little bit of **skill or experience in the subject** to find a dup-target to → I usually just VTC.
- **Well-written/well-researched** questions for a problem that is not easy to find a dup-target for or if the question is about a **different problem** that can be solved by the answers in the dup-target → I usually *upvote* and VTC.

Comment: @ispiro Had I faced this problem, my search query would've been something like `visual studio intellisense stuck execute suggested action`. Testing it now, I can see the dup-target as the second result in Google Search. I personally wouldn't have downvoted the question (probably) but I can see why others did.

Comment: After knowing the answer, it's easy to find what to search for... :)

Comment: @ispiro I only based this on the title of your question and the text in the screenshot :) That being said, it happens to the best of us. Sometimes, what one's looking for is right in front of their eyes but they can't see it. Sometimes I can't seem to know what to type into a search engine until some time passes, so it's fine. Although can be discouraging, `Downvotes != aPunishment`. Just shrug it off and delete the question if you think you've found your answer.

Answer (score 7):

It’s up to you. The community can’t tell you how to vote other than what is already written in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Questions being a duplicate is not a reason to downvote. The tooltip only says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Base your votes on that description.

If the question is not going to help other people to find the right solutions then you are free to downvote. If the question will help others find the duplicate target easier then you can upvote it. **Just because the question is a duplicate is not a reason for a downvote**.

It’s your decision how you wish to interpret the meaning of the downvote/upvote buttons and we rely on your judgement to properly rate content.

Comment: You can't vote on your own questions. However, we do expect others to read it and judge its usefulness. It looks like 3 people didn't find your question very helpful. Perhaps try editing it?

Comment: Is there something wrong with it? (The downvoting was, I assume, because people _do_ downvote duplicates for being duplicates. Hence this question here.)