# Is it common for duplicate questions to get downvotes on meta?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvotes, meta

I have a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419001) on meta (that was migrated from the main Q&A). Originally, the question got a score of 4. Then it was closed as a duplicate, and shortly, it had a score of -4, and the question currently has a score of -6. Same thing happened to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419340). It got a score of 1, later closed as duplicate, and a while later, got a score of -8.

Because of this pattern of downvotes after the questions were closed as duplicates, it makes me wonder, Are my questions downvoted just because they are duplicates? If so, is there something in meta that tells people to downvote duplicate questions?

Comment: Your first question only has 2 upvotes, I find it unlikely it had a score of 4 at one point. And duplicates that don't show research attempts are (often) downvotes across the network, whether than be [main], [meta.so], [DBA.se], [su], etc etc.

Comment: People also tend to be more free with votes on child-metas (network-wide) since there is no reputation associated with the posts. But continuing the research before asking trend: [Is it a good practice to downvote a duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357539/15497888) is one of the first results searching the question you've just asked.

Comment: There's also [Should a duplicate be downvoted or just closed as a duplicate?](/q/404777/15497888) and [Should one downvote a question marked as duplicate?](/q/321757/15497888).

Comment: The upvoters problably changed their votes at some point, for I *did* see a score of 4 at some point

Comment: It is only natural that there is some level of correlation between a question being a duplicate and the same question being poorly researched.

Comment: [This might be worth a read even though it's about the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach the question from a completely different angle. When do you get upvotes on meta posts? When it is something that people resonate with, it won't be any more complicated than that.

Now given that the meta crowd is a pretty small subset of the user base that kind of tend to stick together (for better or worse), say that you post something that has been asked or suggested numerous times already. What do you think will happen?

The votes don't really matter all that much though. Either it gets closed and linked to excellent duplicates, or you get some stellar answers nonetheless. Or both. We do like to show off our knowledge of the site. Again. And again. And again. And again.

(And we also can't resist engaging with people who are in a fit of rage. Again. And again. And...)

Answer (score 5):

> Is it common?

If we only consider **undeleted** meta questions,

- [Total of 9677 questions closed as duplicate in meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3A1+)
- [6633 closed as duplicate with a score>=1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3A1+score%3A1)
- [713 closed as duplicate with score =0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=duplicate%3a1%20score%3a0)

So, around 75% questions of duplicate questions, that are not deleted, got a net positive or a neutral vote - which would suggest it's not that common. Having said that, if we consider deleted posts, this might not hold true anymore.

Comment: How about deleted meta posts?

Comment: @user18807217 It's [probably higher](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405585/can-we-slow-down-on-the-deletes-on-meta-folks), but only moderators can know the exact number of deleted duplicates. You can try to contact one in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com//rooms/41570)